# How do I know which CSS is overriding my background image?

Tags: css

I want a background image on my page (background.png), but some rogue CSS is thwarting me.

[image]

I can see that my style.css from line 39 is being overwritten.  I would think this is being done by something like style.css.  I search and do not find anything but my original desired specification in that file.  I can not find out what css is doing the overriding.

I have searched all the css files I can think of for the specified image (bg_p2_28.jpg).  I have searched all the css files for background, nothing seems to come up.  It is not being specified in the main HTML

I am barely struggling through as a reasonably competent programmer that has not used HTML since the mid 1990's.  I am just trying to modify a template I bought.

What techniques can I use, or how do I  interpret what I have here shown here to figure out what CSS override is ultimately being pushed into the page?

EDIT:

Adding the !important; works.  It feels very dirty for some reason.  I do not know why.  I have tried following the javascript in, but the debugger is confusing to the uninitiated.  Is the Important! a terrible thing to do, or reasonable?  I think it would be useful to understand where these are being set in the java code, but when I search the code, I think the values are stored in variable, so can only be caught at run time.

Comment: While it should be avoided whenever possible, `!important` is pretty much the only thing you can do to override inline styles.  The best solution would be to find out where it is coming from and remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `background: url(src) !important;`, not the perfect solution, but i think it will work for you in this case.

Answer (score 7):

That's coming from the inline `style=""` attribute.

If you don't see it in the HTML source, it's probably being set by Javascript.

You can right-click the element in the inspector and click Break on Attribute Modifications to find out where.

Answer (score 2):

The grey `element.style` means that it's a `style` attribute directly on the element itself.  Any style on an element will override styles from style sheets unless the sytlesheet style is marked with `!important`